# Working script stop working (php,mysql)

Tags: mysql, database

I've got a weird problem.
I created a website on localhost. Everything was working fine. I could connect to my mysql db without any problems.
I decided to put it on external server to show it to my friends. I changed $username, $dbname etc.

Then I decided to work  little with the website back on localhost. And then it started. When I run my script which adds new records to my db (name, message, email) this shows up.

> No database selected

Everything is just the same it was before I decided to put it on the server. What can be the problem?

EDIT: Here's the code of connect.php

```
<?php 

$username ="root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";
$table = "test";

$conn = new mysqli("$host", "$username", "$password", "$table");


if (!$conn) {
    die("Nie udało się połączyć z bazą danych: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

and here's a script implemented into index.php

```
        <?php
        include 'connect.php';


        $sql = "SELECT s_id, name, s_like, s_dislike, message FROM suggestions ORDER BY rand()";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $s_id = $row["s_id"];
        $s_like = $row["s_like"];
        $s_dislike = $row["s_dislike"];

        echo '<p>' . $row["message"] . '</p>';
        echo '<h1 class="podpis">' . $row["name"] . '</h1>';

        mysqli_close($conn);

        ?>
```

and here's the cde of comments.php where I see the message about No database selected.

```
    <?php

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

$username ="root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";
$table = "test";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $table);

$query = "INSERT INTO suggestions (name, email, message) VALUES ('$name', 
'$email', '$message')";

if (mysql_query($query)) {
    echo 'Dodano sugestię!';
    header('Location: index.php');
} else{ die(mysql_error());}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: The main post edited. Sorry :D

Comment: You are using OO to construct `new MySQLi`. So, to query you should use ` $result = $conn->query($sql);` Hope this help - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Your mixing mysqli_ and mysql_ calls, this will cause problems, as well as mysql_ being deprecated.